# Generic template with packed and unpacked padding

Tags: c++, templates, embedded

EDIT: Fixed constructor names in the packed example.

We use this generic template to generate strong types for C++ interfaces:

```
/// @brief template for strong types
    /// Usage:
    /// using MyStrongIntegerRadius = StrongType<uint32_t, struct InteregerRadius>;
    /// see: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/08/strong-types-for-strong-interfaces/
    template<typename T, typename Parameter>
    class StrongType
    {
    public:
        constexpr StrongType()
        {
        }
        constexpr explicit StrongType(T const& value) : value_(value)
        {
        }
        constexpr explicit StrongType(T&& value) : value_(std::move(value))
        {
        }
        T& get()
        {
            return value_;
        }
        T const& get() const
        {
            return value_;
        }
// More code...
    private:
        T value_ { };
    };
```

This works fine in general. Now I have to deal with saving several of these strong typed variables  based on `uint8_t` to flash memory on a 32 bit embedded device. Since the flash space is very limited, I need to use a packed form of the template. This template could look like this:

```
    template<typename T, typename Parameter>
    class StrongTypePacked
    {
    public:
        constexpr StrongTypePacked()
        {
        }
        constexpr explicit StrongTypePacked(T const& value) : value_(value)
        {
        }
        constexpr explicit StrongTypePacked(T&& value) : value_(std::move(value))
        {
        }
        T& get()
        {
            return value_;
        }
        T const& get() const
        {
            return value_;
        }
// More code...
    private:
        T value_ { };
    } __attribute__((__packed__));
```

This creates a lot of redundant code, which I would like to avoid if possible. Thus my question is, if it is possible to write a generic form of this template for which packing can be activated at need? Note that the project uses C++14 and that pre-processor usage is limited due to functional safety requirements on code readability.

Comment: If you add a 3rd template argument to choose between packed and not packed then the compiler should reuse the same code for both if it actually is identical.

Comment: I don't see the need of packing for serialization. Do you `memcpy` to have the need of packed? serialization cannot really use memcpy, as you have to also handle endianess.

Comment: It's only got one member variable in it. Is it ever *not* packed? Does packing make a difference?

Comment: @Jarod42 Generally, you are right, serialization can be realized using more sophisticated techniques. However, I'd like to avoid these for this specific set of projects, as flash and computing resources are extremely tight.

Comment: @user253751 I do not know if it is packed in this specific case or if padding is added. The code is part of a platform thus I can't rely on a specific case. Unless I miss something and the standard guarantees that the resulting object is always packed.

Comment: That said I actually tried something like this just yesterday and couldn't get it to work. The problem is your `StrongTypePacked` class is wrong. The constructor must take a packed `T`, the `get` method must return a packed `T`, The `value_` should be a packed `T` because the class is supposedly packed. Initializing a packed `T` with a not-packed `T` should give an error. Problem is the whole class isn't packed at all as you can see if you look at sizeof() for some example `T`: https://godbolt.org/z/Toz8nzbMb I can't figure out how to pack a template at all, gcc always ignores it.

Comment: I don't really see why a class with one member variable and no explicit `alignas` would ever need padding

Comment: @user253751 The class shouldn't be packed but the T should be.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow that doesn't make sense though. Packing is something that affects the offset of the class members within the class. It doesn't make sense to pack something from the outside. There's no such thing as "a packed int" for example.

Comment: @user253751 The intent would be to have the packed apply recursively to T. But that doesn't work. As shown in my godbolt link nothing gets packed at all.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow that's because packing from the outside doesn't make sense - all instances of MyClass have the same layout, end of story - you can't say that some have different internal layout than others - so the MyClass inside a StrongTypePacked<MyClass> always has that internal layout too.

Comment: @user253751 I know. So how would you move the packed inside so the T is packed? <source>:27:48: warning: 'packed' attribute ignored for field of type 'T' [-Wattributes]
   27 |        `__attribute__((__packed__)) T value_ { };`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow T is supposed to be a scalar variable. Wrapping it into StrongType makes sure the compiler complains if e.g. a diameter and a radius have type uint8_t and you mixe these. Using StrongTypes with T = uint8_t, the compiler is able to distinguish them and complains. Thus there is no need for propagation of the packing. The only thing that needs to be guaranteed is, that uint8_t when wrapped in StrongType uses 1 Byte.

Comment: @PaulR. Except that is not what it does. The class will always be sizeof(T). What changes is that the alignment requirement is set to 1, which might actually be what you want. But if T is not a fundamental type then that lack of alignment will break stuff when you use the T. Maybe add a `requires (std::is_fundamental_v<T>)`.

Comment: @PaulR. Is it normally possible to pack a scalar variable?

Comment: @user253751 You can't pack a scalar variable but you can pack a struct containing one. As said this doesn't affect the size but it does affect the alignment.

Comment: "functional safety requirements"  Then you can't use C++.